# TFileListBox Component Finding Files Which No Longer Exist

Tags: windows, delphi, vcl, file-copying, filelist

I am using Delphi 7 on Windows 7 and have an application which uses a TFileListBox component to iterate through files in a directory and copies them to a backup directory.

I'm experiencing some strange behavior whereby the TFileListBox is detecting files which do not exist within the directory?? The directory I am coping from contains 75 files but the TFileListBox detects over 100 files.

I changed my explorer settings to display hidden/system files but still cannot see where these extra files are coming from.

I was wondering whether this Windows 7 Previous Versions was playing a part in this problem as I am fairly sure that the extra files the TFileListBox is detecting did used to once reside in this directory but were deleted...

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us some of the names of the non-existant files? Also, what happens when you try `FileExists()` on these non-existant files?

Comment: Adding FileExists() doesnt't resolve the issue. The files names vary, there are .zip, .doc etc.

Comment: Please show us the file names! What happens when you call `FileExists()` on the non-existant files. What is the return value?

Comment: If you go the command prompt and type dir \*.\* are those files there?

Comment: Here are some of the file names which the TFileListBox is detecting (which don't exist):

C:\Program Files\MyAppDirectory\Database\data.zip
C:\Program Files\MyAppDirectory\Database\New word document.doc

Performing a dir *.* in the directory, or a dir *.* /s, or a dir *.* /ah, or a dir *.* /as does not display the files. This is crazy? Where is it getting the files from?

Comment: Are you an administrator and is Windows UAC off?

Comment: I can smell the virtual store

Comment: Ahhh just found something interesting...I performed a **dir data.zip /s** from the c: root directory and the file was found in **C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\MyAppDirectory\Database**...I deleted the file and now my app no longer detects this file...

Comment: Not sure if I can recommend software here, but for such searches, the free Search Everything (www.voidtools.com) is an excellent and very fast tool. Much easier than "dir data.zip /s".

Comment: @Rudy Much easier that `dir /s`?!! It's pretty hard to imagine anything easier than that, especially considering that it's what OP already knows.

Comment: `dir /s` requires you to open the command line, type commands like `cd \ ` and `dir data.zip /s` and then wait for a long time, while it only takes one click to open Everything, a few keystrokes to enter `data.zip` and find all occurrences of the file. Response is almost immediate, which can't be said about `dir /s`. Try the app. You'll like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have worked out from the comments above that the issue is related to the Virtual Store which is used when your application is virtualized.  The virtual store was introduced with Windows Vista as part of the move to running applications without administrator rights.  These files are appearing in the virtual store because your application is writing to the program files directory, to which standard users do not have write privileges.

Virtualization was introduced to help deal with legacy applications that were not going to be recompiled to take account of the new Vista policies.  Nowadays you simply should not be building a virtualized application.

You can disable virtualization by linking an application manifest to your application that includes the `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker"/>` section.

When you do this, you will no doubt find some other problems because your application may attempt to write to the program files directory, the HKLM section of the registry, etc.  Whilst it may seem painful to make these changes, they are worth the effort.

Comment: If its an old program is there something in the code that can be added so that it will work on XP as well as Vista/7?

Comment: @Jon I don't understand the question. Are you asking if the manifest resource can be added to an app and it still works on XP? If so then yes, XP just ignores that part of the manifest.

Comment: No I mean if the Delphi code is saying File.Write(C:\Program Files) is there something in the code that needs to check for UAC or the OS and then write to the correct place or is there one location that can be specified eg SpecialFolder.ProgramData and that will work on XP & Vista

Comment: @Jon You need to find somewhere else to write that data. But that's a different topic. We can't really deal with it in these comments. Something equivalent to SpecialFolder.ProgramData might be appropriate but be warned that users cannot delete from that location for some reason. You could consider the common documents locations. It all really depends on what you are storing. Note that at present with UAC, these files will be per-user. Perhaps that's actually fine for you in which case you just stick the file somewhere in the user's profile.